# How can I make the input name include the full name with a space as a string would?

Tags: javascript

I have this code that works perfect except for one thing. My names that need to be inputted have spaces that the code will not recognize. I've tried " " but its not working. 

For example, when I type in the Additional Purchase in the input box it works great until I get to the "space" then my description disappears?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
       var data = [


                {   // Reject Title
                    name: 'Additional Purchase', 
                    // Reject Reason(s) w/Links 
                    description:    
                    '<div><a href="PDFRejectData/A005.pdf" target="PDF" class="reasonLink" >FUND ONLY ALLOWS NATURAL PERSONS</a> </div><div><a href="PDFRejectData/A007.pdf" target="PDF" class="reasonLink">MASTER ACOUNT STATUS IS CLOSED</a> </div>'                



                },
                {
                    name: 'Address Change',     // Reject Title
                    description:        // Reject Reasons with Links
                    'The Other Writer'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Asset Transfer',     // Reject Title
                    description: 'The CodeIgniter Writer'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Banking and Options', // Reject Title
                    description: 'Made Up Person #1'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Beneficiary',
                    description: 'Another Made Up Person'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Close Account',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'CWR',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Date of Birth',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'DividendCapital Gains Maintenance',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Domestic Bank on File',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Duplicate Statements',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                                    },
                {
                    name: 'Full Transfer Residual Followup',        // Reject Title
                    description:        // Reject Reasons with Links
                    'The Other Writer'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Legal Document',     // Reject Title
                    description: 'The CodeIgniter Writer'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Maintain Brokerage Account Link', // Reject Title
                    description: 'Made Up Person #1'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Maintain Control Person Client Information',
                    description: 'Another Made Up Person'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Maintain Mutual Fund Exch/Red Options',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Maintain SBS PLan',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Merge/Expand Rule Failure in Batch 1',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Micro Deposit Reject',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Money Movement',
                    description: 'That Guy'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Mutual Fund Freezes',
                    description: 'That Guy'

                }
            ];


            // Suggest section holder
            var $suggestedHL = $('.suggest-holder');
            // Suggestions UL
            var $suggestedUL = $('ul', $suggestedHL);
            // Suggestions LI
            var $suggestedLI = $('li', $suggestedHL);
            // Selected Items UL
            var $selectedUL = $('#selected-suggestions');
            // Keyboard Nav Index
            var index = -1;

            // Add a suggestion to the selected holder
            function addSuggestion(el){
                $selectedUL.append($('<li>' + el.find('.suggest-description').html() + '</li>'));
            }

            $('input', $suggestedHL).on({
                keyup: function(e){
                    var m = false;
                    if(e.which == 38){
                        // Down arrow - Check that we've not tried to select before the first item
                        if(--index < 0){
                            index = 0;
                        }

                        // Set a variable to show that we've done some keyboard navigation
                        m = true;
                    }else if(e.which == 40){
                        // Up arrow - Check that index is not beyond the last item
                        if(++index > $suggestedLI.length - 1){
                            index = $suggestedLI.length-1;
                        }

                        // Set a variable to show that we've done some keyboard navigation
                        m = true;
                    }

                    // Check we've done keyboard navigation
                    if(m){
                        // Remove the active class
                        $('li.active', $suggestedHL).removeClass('active');
                        $suggestedLI.eq(index).addClass('active');
                    }else if(e.which == 27){
                        index = -1;
                        // Esc key
                        $suggestedUL.hide();
                    }else if(e.which == 13){
                        // Enter key
                        if(index > -1){
                            addSuggestion($('li.active', $suggestedHL));
                            index = -1;
                            $('li.active', $suggestedHL).removeClass('active');
                        }
                    }else{
                        index = -1;
                        // Clear the ul
                        $suggestedUL.empty();

                        // Cache the search term
                        $search = $(this).val();

                        // Search regular expression
                        $search = new RegExp($search.replace(/[^0-9a-z_]/i), 'i');

                        // Loop through the array
                        for(var i in data){
                            if(data[i].name.match($search)){
                                $suggestedUL.append($("<li><span class='suggest-name'>" + data[i].name + "</span><span class='suggest-description'>" + data[i].description + "</span></li>"));
                            }
                        }

                        // Show the ul
                        $suggestedUL.show();
                    }
                    if($(this).val() == ''){
                        $suggestedUL.hide();
                    }
                },
                keydown: function(e){
                    if(e.which == 38 || e.which == 40 || e.which == 13){
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                },
                focus: function(e){
                    if($(this).val() != ''){
                        $suggestedUL.show();
                    }
                }
            });

            $suggestedHL.on('click', 'li', function(e){
                addSuggestion($(this));
            });

            $('body').on('click', function(e) {
                if (!$(e.target).closest('.suggest-holder li, .suggest-holder input').length) {
                    $suggestedUL.hide();
                };
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be solved if you add a space character (without quotes) to your regular expression. So turn this line:

```
  $search = new RegExp($search.replace(/[^0-9a-z_]/i), 'i');
```

Into this:

```
  $search = new RegExp($search.replace(/[^0-9a-z_ ]/i), 'i');
```

I've put together a quick test:

```js
var data = [


  { // Reject Title
    name: 'Additional Purchase',
    // Reject Reason(s) w/Links 
    description: '<div><a href="PDFRejectData/A005.pdf" target="PDF" class="reasonLink" >FUND ONLY ALLOWS NATURAL PERSONS</a> </div><div><a href="PDFRejectData/A007.pdf" target="PDF" class="reasonLink">MASTER ACOUNT STATUS IS CLOSED</a> </div>'



  },
  {
    name: 'Address Change', // Reject Title
    description: // Reject Reasons with Links
      'The Other Writer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Asset Transfer', // Reject Title
    description: 'The CodeIgniter Writer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Banking and Options', // Reject Title
    description: 'Made Up Person #1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Beneficiary',
    description: 'Another Made Up Person'
  },
  {
    name: 'Close Account',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'CWR',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Date of Birth',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'DividendCapital Gains Maintenance',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Domestic Bank on File',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Duplicate Statements',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Full Transfer Residual Followup', // Reject Title
    description: // Reject Reasons with Links
      'The Other Writer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Legal Document', // Reject Title
    description: 'The CodeIgniter Writer'
  },
  {
    name: 'Maintain Brokerage Account Link', // Reject Title
    description: 'Made Up Person #1'
  },
  {
    name: 'Maintain Control Person Client Information',
    description: 'Another Made Up Person'
  },
  {
    name: 'Maintain Mutual Fund Exch/Red Options',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Maintain SBS PLan',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Merge/Expand Rule Failure in Batch 1',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Micro Deposit Reject',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Money Movement',
    description: 'That Guy'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mutual Fund Freezes',
    description: 'That Guy'

  }
];


// Suggest section holder
var $suggestedHL = $('.suggest-holder');
// Suggestions UL
var $suggestedUL = $('ul', $suggestedHL);
// Suggestions LI
var $suggestedLI = $('li', $suggestedHL);
// Selected Items UL
var $selectedUL = $('#selected-suggestions');
// Keyboard Nav Index
var index = -1;

// Add a suggestion to the selected holder
function addSuggestion(el) {
  $selectedUL.append($('<li>' + el.find('.suggest-description').html() + '</li>'));
}

$('input', $suggestedHL).on({
  keyup: function(e) {
    var m = false;
    if (e.which == 38) {
      // Down arrow - Check that we've not tried to select before the first item
      if (--index < 0) {
        index = 0;
      }

      // Set a variable to show that we've done some keyboard navigation
      m = true;
    } else if (e.which == 40) {
      // Up arrow - Check that index is not beyond the last item
      if (++index > $suggestedLI.length - 1) {
        index = $suggestedLI.length - 1;
      }

      // Set a variable to show that we've done some keyboard navigation
      m = true;
    }

    // Check we've done keyboard navigation
    if (m) {
      // Remove the active class
      $('li.active', $suggestedHL).removeClass('active');
      $suggestedLI.eq(index).addClass('active');
    } else if (e.which == 27) {
      index = -1;
      // Esc key
      $suggestedUL.hide();
    } else if (e.which == 13) {
      // Enter key
      if (index > -1) {
        addSuggestion($('li.active', $suggestedHL));
        index = -1;
        $('li.active', $suggestedHL).removeClass('active');
      }
    } else {
      index = -1;
      // Clear the ul
      $suggestedUL.empty();

      // Cache the search term
      $search = $(this).val();

      // Search regular expression
      $search = new RegExp($search.replace(/[^0-9a-z_\s]/i), 'i');

      // Loop through the array
      for (var i in data) {
        if (data[i].name.match($search)) {
          $suggestedUL.append($("<li><span class='suggest-name'>" + data[i].name + "</span><span class='suggest-description'>" + data[i].description + "</span></li>"));
        }
      }

      // Show the ul
      $suggestedUL.show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $suggestedUL.hide();
    }
  },
  keydown: function(e) {
    if (e.which == 38 || e.which == 40 || e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  focus: function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      $suggestedUL.show();
    }
  }
});

$suggestedHL.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  addSuggestion($(this));
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.suggest-holder li, .suggest-holder input').length) {
    $suggestedUL.hide();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="suggest-holder">
  <input type="text">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
(Try typing something like <code>additional purchase</code> or <code>date of birth</code>)
```

Comment: That works Perfect! Just one other question please. The description that is shown below the name are various hyperlinks.  For easy updates is there any way to add my hyperlinks with a carriage return after each one? Currently, code will only allow them all on the same line which makes it difficult to update. Thank you!

Comment: @user3806255 In the output, or in the source? If you want to separate them in the output, you could possibly wrap each link in a `<p>` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: To be able to type in the description over multiple lines in your source code you can either wrap each line in quotes and concatenate the lines/strings using `+`. Alternatively you can enclose the whole description in backticks ( ` ) instead of quotes. This will turn the string into a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) where multi-line strings are supported. [Examples for both at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings).